# How do I escape a mixture of " and ' in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
/[Path='/'].applicationPool:"ASP.NET v4.0"
```

This whole line is actually a parameter, so I would like to put single quotes around it. But it doesn't work because it already includes single quotes.

I have tried the ` in front of the single quoates without success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to surround with quotes and escape the inner quotes with backtick:

```
"/[Path='/'].applicationPool:`"ASP.NET v4.0`""
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to double each nested single quote:

```
'/[Path=''/''].applicationPool:"ASP.NET v4.0"'
```